# Selecting all columns with Inner Join in Active Record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, rails-activerecord

In the Ruby on Rails Guide I see examples using Joins. For example

```
Category.joins(:posts)
```

results in the query

```
SELECT categories.* FROM categories
  INNER JOIN posts ON posts.category_id = categories.id
```

This is all well and good, but how can I get returned both the categories AND posts columns using Active Record? Or am I totally missing something with SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `#includes`:

```
Category.includes(:posts)
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more detailed answer. At least this puts me in the right directions. Thanks.

Comment: `#includes` eagerly loads the association provided which seems like that was what you needed. It should explain it more in that Rails guide.

Comment: The problem I'm finding is that when I render the data onto the view, I'm only getting the attributes from `Category` and not `Post`.

Comment: If you have an association on your Category class called `:posts` then AR will automatically select the post attributes and you access them through `category.posts`. You can do it without the `#includes` but it will do another query each time you call `#posts` on a category (N+1 query). `#includes` will do it (usually) as a single query.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to ask the question again but pertaining to my situation since it's going to go beyond the scope of this question.