# How can I select columns return with joins method in Active Record without associations?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am working on Rails model, that is mapped on an external (non default) database table.

I need to make a join to obtain the data I need to instantiate an object.

I am using active record's functions:

```
self.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts ON accounts.code = customers.code").select("customers.code, accounts.email, accounts.firstname, accounts.password_hash").where('accounts.code = ?', my_param)[0]
```

The model class is:

```
class User::Customer < User

  self.establish_connection :external_db
  self.table_name = "customers"


  attr_accessor :password_hash
  attr_accessor :firstname
  attr_accessor :email
end
```

This is the query that it does:

```
SELECT customers.code, accounts.email, accounts.firstname, accounts.password_hash FROM `customers` LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts ON accounts.code = customers.code WHERE (accounts.code = '11111111')
```

So the query it is right, but my object:

```
#<User::Customer id: nil, code: "11111111">
```

has only the attributes of its table.
I expected that, because I set the attr_accessor of the other attributes, Rails map the result of the query to my object, but surely I am missing something and haven't fully undestand how this work.

**Edit:** I've forgotten to mention the fact that I have no association, so I can't use this solution.

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947820/selecting-all-columns-with-inner-join-in-active-record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having `attr_accessor` you'll be able to get the attributes by:

```
@user.email
```

You need to specify a `to_s` instance method to achieve what you want:

```
class User::Customer < User
  #...
  def to_s
    "#{password_hash}, #{firstname}, #{email}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I can't understand why if I set attr_accessor :email. When I try to do user.email, don't return me the result!

Comment: @ciaoben `attr_accessor` works in a way, that it allows you to access set attributes. So, firstly, you should set the attribute (`@user.email = 'test@email.com'`) prior accessing it.

Comment: thanks, make sense. I suspect has something to do even with the fact that I was overwriting the default ActiveRecord getters/setters methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes not showing in object's inspection. but remove all `attr_accessor` and on `User::Customer` object (say `@user`), try direct your joined table's column name. like this,

```
@user.password_hash
```

It will give you result.

Comment: Yes, it works. But why? Why I can't see if I inspect it?

Comment: May be, you need to overwrite `to_s` method.

Comment: Yes, you're right, like Andrey said. But I am missing something about the `attr_accessor`s

Comment: Why with `attr_accessor` doesn't work, and if I drop them it works?